# Combining IMPORTRANGE, SUMIFS, QUERY with cells that contain numbers and text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

I'm having an issue combining `SUMIFS` with `ImportRange` in Google Sheets. I found answers suggesting to nest it with `QUERY`. However, the issue is that one of my criteria is non-numerical.

Formula in spreadsheet 2:

```
=query(ImportRange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_F-1tyYhlHfjjE2151T52FvcwGrtKUvB12WSJR0WRT",
 "inquiries.app date.bonus!a4:u"), 
 "select sum (Col13) where (Col13='<>' 
  and Col14 >= date'"&TEXT(today()-30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"') label sum (Col13) ''")`
```

- imports data from spreadsheet 1 using `ImportRange`
- sums Column M values (spreadsheet 1)
- if Column M is **not blank** and if Column N date is within the past month (spreadsheet 1)

I get an error message:

> `#VALUE!` Unable to parse query string for function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC

FYI
Column M values are

- blank
- text (yes, NA)
- number

Column N values are

- blank
- text (NA)
- dates

### How can I get query condition 1 to be "Col 13 is number"?

From all the answers I found online, `QUERY` doesn't like non-numeric data/mixed data. Some solutions suggested using the `ArrayFormula` or `FILTER` - but these used data within the same spreadsheet (didn't `ImportRange`.

Other solutions used `IF(ISNUMBER))` nested with my formula. I also tried changing the column format to "plain text" which didn't work.

Some formulas I've tried:

```
=query(isnumber(ImportRange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_F-1tyYhlHfjjE2151T52FvcwGrtKUvB12WSJR0WRT",
"inquiries.app date.bonus!a4:u")),
"select Sum (Col13) where (Col13)='<>' 
 and (Col14)>=date'"&TEXT(today()-30,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label sum (Col13) ''")`
```

> Value Error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col13

```
=query(ImportRange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_F-1tyYhlHfjjE2151T52FvcwGrtKUvB12WSJR0WRT",
 "inquiries.app date.bonus!a4:u"), 
 "select,sum (Col13) where (Col13)='<>' 
  and Col14= date'"&TEXT(today()-30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label sum (Col13) ''")`
```

> Value Error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "," ", "" at line 1, column 7. Was expecting one of: "true" ... "false" ... "date" ... "timeofday" ... "datetime" ... "timestamp" ... "min" ... "max" ... "avg" ... "count" ... "sum" ... "no_values" ... "no_format" ... "is" ... "null" ... "year" ... "month" ... "day" ... "hour" ... "minute" ... "second" ... "millisecond" ... "with" ... "contains" ... "starts" ... "ends" ... "matches" ... "like" ... "now" ... "dateDiff" ... "quarter" ... "lower" ... "upper" ... "dayOfWeek" ... "toDate" ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ... "(" ... "*" ... "-" ...

---

Is there a way to get my formula to work without adding a new column to my source data? I'm wondering if I can use `ISNUMBER` or `ArrayFormula`?

---

### EDIT

Here are some sample sheets:
[Sheet 2 (contains formula)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZGu8WaMiQ49-JTBVTe1MuCP9vYqPnKUamD2kgpYDPM/edit?usp=sharing)
[Sheet 1 (source data)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HrEGCH-MCfeGh952VkpONRfSoLbZVLir5BNgFWK0PH8/edit?usp=sharing)

To summarize, my issue is `QUERY` not summing numbers in Col M (Col13). In `QUERY` I've tried using:

- `<>` and `<>""` (is not blank)
- `Col13 is not null`
- `Col13>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1HrEGCH-MCfeGh952VkpONRfSoLbZVLir5BNgFWK0PH8", "inquiries.app date.bonus!A5:O")*1),
 "select Col13 
  where Col13 is not null 
    and Col14 >="&DATEVALUE(TODAY()-30), 0))))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t9e8YECGdvfBYmlORQXIcKXXiCDj8xeQdObUHIidbyg/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Wow, this is super close! the answer should be 200. Not sure where it’s getting 250. In the source SS1, 2nd tab, I manually filtered what I’m looking for (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HrEGCH-MCfeGh952VkpONRfSoLbZVLir5BNgFWK0PH8). In the first sheet (locked) in SS1, I included the formula I originally had written (before I realized I needed to import the range.  I wonder why it’s summing the extra 50?

Comment: because I changed N5 date hance that extra 50 >> blue cells

Comment: Is there a way to replace “where Col13 is not null” with something that specifies Col13 is a number? I’ve tried SUMPRODUCT and FILTER and ISNUMBER, but I don’t think I’m nesting it properly. You blew my mind with ARRAYFORMULA- I didn’t realize it could be used with IMPORTRANGE! Everything I found online said it could only be used within the same spreadsheet

Comment: there is no such parameter as "Col13 is a number" nor anything similar to it

Comment: You changed N5? I see it in the screenshot, but don’t see the change in the sample sheets?

Comment: the formula from the answer is referencing spreadsheet from answer not from your sample sheet - thats why

Comment: you are a magician!! sorry - i was using the mobile app, so i had a difficult time copying/pasting properly. the formula works perfectly :) THANK YOU

Comment: last question(s): i am trying to do YTD and TOTAL as well. I used your formula, changing the date ranges, but get 0 (or false). Is there something I need to tweak to get it to work? I put the formulas in Sheet1 of SS2 (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZGu8WaMiQ49-JTBVTe1MuCP9vYqPnKUamD2kgpYDPM/edit#gid=0). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @quesyrahsarah sheet updated

Comment: thank you! you're right about YTD. the date range is wrong (i copied it incorrectly). it should be 'Col14 >="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1) and Col14 <="&DATEVALUE(TODAY())'. however, it doesnt give me the right answer. am i doing something wrong? really appreciate all your help. you're a genius!

Comment: see now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZGu8WaMiQ49-JTBVTe1MuCP9vYqPnKUamD2kgpYDPM/edit#gid=0&range=B1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Column M` and `Column N`from the source spreadsheet include text and numbers / dates. Blank cells doesn't cause problems.

In both columns, you should remove the text values before passing the imported values to `QUERY`.

While it could apparently be "elegant" to have a single formula that does all the job, this makes the spreadsheet harder to understand, troubleshoot and maintain, so at least in the meantime that you understand how each task should be done, avoid to use the "all-in-one-formula" approach.

- Use one sheet for a IMPORTRANGE formula (`=IMPORTRANGE(...)`). The next step assumes that this formula was added to a sheet named `Sheet1`.
- Since your formula only use Col13, and Col14 you could use something like the following as the first argument of QUERY

  - `=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!M:M),Sheet1!M:M,),IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!N:N),Sheet1!N:N,)})`. Let say that this formula is added to a sheet named `Sheet2`.
- Use Sheet2!A:B as the first argument of `QUERY` but instead of `Col13`, and `Col14` use `A` and `B` respectively.

Comment: thank you. actually @user0 got the formula to work! no need to separate text and number values

Comment: @quesyrahsarah actually it separate them, just it does in a different way.